# Link Prefetching in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, prefetch

If I add `<link rel="prefetch" href="http://website.loc/image.png">`, the browser (Firefox 46) will prefetch the image.

However if I put the same tag within an Angular 2 template, the prefetching does not happen event though the `link` element shows up in the DOM

Do any of you use link prefetching in your angular templates?

Answer (score 0):

this is github link which has
[Angular template cache](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) example

and lazy prefetching

http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/10/01/angularjs-partials-lazy-prefetching-strategy-weighted-directed-graph/

Comment: Thank you that's an interesting read.  It is for Angular 1 though, and it requires a Javascript solution rather than the native HTML5 feature (http://caniuse.com/link-rel-prefetch)